# spring-boot-starter-amqp.1.7.4.Release can't stop

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We use spring-boot-starter-amqp.1.7.4.Release 。when we try to kill this process，can’t stop it。

this is thread dump。please help me？

========================================================

```
"Thread-57" #104 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4420038800 nid=0x39f6 in Object.wait() [0x00007f443d8d2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:49)
    - locked <0x000000008ad818e0> (a com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:91)
    - locked <0x000000008ad818e0> (a com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:32)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:366)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicCancel(ChannelN.java:1280)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:980)
    - locked <0x0000000089d2a198> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.basicCancel(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.basicCancel(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:392)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doShutdown(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:902)
    - locked <0x0000000089d2ac98> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.shutdown(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:558)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.destroy(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:522)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.destroy(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.java:210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:256)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:552)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:933)
    - locked <0x0000000088706660> (a java.lang.Object)

"SIGTERM handler" #310 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4430014800 nid=0x39f1 in Object.wait() [0x00007f44588d9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1252)
    - locked <0x0000000089e1f030> (a org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1326)
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:106)
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1.run(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:46)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(Shutdown.java:123)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.sequence(Shutdown.java:167)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Shutdown.java:212)
    - locked <0x00000000877fa068> (a java.lang.Class for java.lang.Shutdown)
    at java.lang.Terminator$1.handle(Terminator.java:52)
    at sun.misc.Signal$1.run(Signal.java:212)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

========================================================

## add version info

```
springBootVersion = "1.5.7.RELEASE"
```

## springVersion = "5.0.1.RELEASE"

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:$springBootVersion"
compile "org.springframework:spring-tx:$springVersion"
compile "org.springframework:spring-core:$springVersion"
compile "org.springframework:spring-beans:$springVersion"
compile "org.springframework:spring-context:$springVersion"
compile "org.springframework:spring-expression:$springVersion"
compile "org.springframework:spring-aop:$springVersion"
compile "org.springframework:spring-context-support:$springVersion"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:$springBootVersion"
```

=========================================================

Comment: There is no such thing as `spring-boot-starter-amqp.1.7.4.Release` - you seem to be mixing Boot and spring-amqp versions. You also need to provide much more information - configuration etc.

Comment: NOW, I HAVE PAST VERSION INFO .

Answer (score 0):

1.7.4 is nearly 2 years old; the current 1.7.x version is 1.7.12.

Similarly the current boot 1.5.x version is 1.5.19.

Furthermore the proper version of Boot to use with Spring Framework is 2.0.x. The current 2.0.x version is 2.0.8 (Spring 5.0.12).

It's generally better to [let boot manage all the dependency versions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.19.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-dependency-management) (there is a gradle plugin).

That way, you don't have to worry about which version is compatible with which.

I suggest, first of all, you get your versions aligned properly and more up-to-date.

All that being said, the thread is blocked in the rabbitmq java client (on `basicCancel`).

> `at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicCancel(ChannelN.java:1280)`

I don't know what conditions can cause that. Is there anything of interest in the application logs?

You would be better asking the rabbitmq engineers what could cause this; they monitor the `rabbitmq-users` Google group much more often than Stack Overflow.